# PHP not executing on Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a site which uses a simply php script to send an email when it is called.  However the email is never being sent.  I've tested this on my universities servers and it worked fine.  **Is there anything I have to do to make sure the php is getting processed by AWS?  Do I have to configure my bucket a specific way?**

I am new to AWS, but I have had success with a previous site so I am unsure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP won't ever execute on Amazon S3. It's a storage service, not a compute service. If you want PHP, you'll need EC2.

Comment: Good to know!  What amazon service am I looking for then?

Comment: Depends on your comfort level. Elastic Beanstalk is fairly easy but somewhat restricted. EC2 gives you more control but you're managing your own servers.